# print only rows which contain only one copy of a value in the first column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a bunch of files, and each looks like this:

```
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1649:2180    Ha9_00011743    100.0   33  0   0   100 2   274 306 7.8e-12 65.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1649:2180    Ha5_00006578    100.0   33  0   0   100 2   98  130 7.8e-12 65.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1649:2180    Ha12_00033467   100.0   33  0   0   100 2   91  123 7.8e-12 65.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6891:2170    Ha2_00026275    87.9    33  4   0   2   100 27  59  9.3e-13 68.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6891:2170    Ha13_00015465   87.9    33  4   0   2   100 884 916 9.3e-13 68.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6891:2170    Ha17_00009154   87.9    33  4   0   2   100 420 452 9.3e-13 68.9
```

I want to keep only those lines where there the first column is unique. This is my desired out put:

```
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KISS approach in `awk`: maintain one array of the lines, and one of counts - then print only the lines whose count is 1 at the end:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0; c[$1]++} END{for (i in a) {if (c[i] == 1) print a[i]}}' file
```

Alternatively, if you have a version of `uniq` that supports the `-w` (`--check-chars`) option and:

1. your data is sorted on the first field; and
2. the first field's width is constant

then you could use that instead:

```
uniq -uw 40 file
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
```

This has the advantage of preserving the original file's order - if that is important for your application.

Comment: Your awk is almost identical to mine. `uniq` solution is nice though.

Comment: Yeah.  I do like the `uniq` solution.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou your "double pass" solution is nice b/c it preserves order - unless I'm missing something, your single pass solution only prints the first field, rather than the whole line?

Comment: Ooops.... You are right. You don't miss anything... i missed `$0`.

Comment: A preserving order (with one scan) is possible: [read my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419975/265604).

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be that. Requires double parsing of the same file but the results are printed in order :

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{f1[$1]++;next}f1[$1]==1' file1 file1
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
```

Comment: Depending on how big the files are and how much of the contents will be printed, one or the other of these may be better.  It's not necessarily bad to double parse and has the advantage of preserving order.

Comment: It is possible to do only one scan and have an stable sort, [read my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419975/265604).

Answer (score 1):

Given only that the input files are sorted, the following will work on any POSIX-compliant system:

```
sed 's/ .*//' file.txt | uniq -u | join - file.txt
```

If the space separators are actually tabs in the original document, you can replace the `sed` invocation with `cut -f1 file.txt` and leave the rest the same.

Comment: Well, since it's the first column you can use `cut` for the first case, too: `cut -d' ' -f1`  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with `sort`, with the -k option to specify which fields you want to consider for sort.

```
sort -k 1,1 -u <file>
```

or with awk, using -F to delimit fields, and ignoring any duplicate lines in `_`.

```
awk -F' ' '!_[$1]++' <file>
```

This will print the entire line for each first occurence of a value in the first colum.  On your sample text, both of these commands would output:

```
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1649:2180    Ha9_00011743    100.0   33  0   0   100 2   274 306 7.8e-12 65.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6891:2170    Ha2_00026275    87.9    33  4   0   2   100 27  59  9.3e-13 68.9
```

**EDIT: updated to account for truly unique instances of column 1, not deduplication**

```
awk '{col1[$1]++; !lines[$1] && lines[$1]=$0} 
     END { for (key in col1) if (col1[key]==1) print lines[key] }' <file>
```

Would result in:

```
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128    Ha6_00047653    90.9    33  3   0   2   100 173 205 5.1e-11 63.2
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:6099:2062    B2KZF9_PICAB    100.0   33  0   0   1   99  73  105 2.4e-13 70.9
HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1477:2147    Ha1_00044161    80.6    31  6   0   94  2   1   31  5.1e-11 63.2
```

Comment: OP expects 'truly unique' lines... for example line `HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1649:2180` should not be printed.

Comment: @ George Vasiliou, yes. True. I do not want HWI-ST913:300:C5W5DACXX:7:1101:1629:2128, because there are 3 examples of that.

Answer (score 0):

To have only one scan of the file **and** print uniq lines in the same order as the input file, use:

In GNU awk (to use "sorted_in" to ensure an ordered scan of the array): use three arrays:

1. One to count repeated lines (c[]),
2. one for the sort order of the lines (s[])and
3. one for the lines them-self (v[])

At the end, print only the lines whose count is 1.

```
awk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ; i=0}
        !c[$1]++{s[++i]=$1;v[i]=$0}
     END{for(i in v){if(c[s[i]]==1){print v[i]}}}' infile
```

Note that the `!c[$1]++` will capture only the first appearance of first field